# Removing a ceiling light and replacing its light switch with a smart switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch

Title says it all: I have a ceiling light I want to remove completely, but utilize the location of the existing light switch for a smart switch to control a different set of lights with smart bulbs. I haven't had any luck googling it, but I need to know if its possible and if so how to wire up the smart switch so that it gets power and can toggle my smart bulbs and cap off the wiring from the removed light fixture at the same time. The smart switch wouldn't be physically controlling anything on the same circuit. Thank you for any advice on this!

Comment: Possible, probably take some rewiring, replacing/repairing drywall.  Rooms must have a light switch by the door/s to turn on a light(to keep you from stepping on legos).

Comment: Title doesn't say enough. If all wiring was done in one standard way, we'd just say "do this, then that". However every circuit is different. Without knowing more it is difficult to advise.  It is often *not* possible. Also note that Code requires that there be a light switch *which controls a light in the room* or alternately a receptacle, and the light switch must work. That is for the benefit of guests, especially guests who wear uniforms of EMT, fire or police.

Comment: So to make sure I'm understanding correctly: you're going to put a smart switch in place that you want to have control smart bulbs throughout the room, but no longer to control the overhead light?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?